# Does the pullback commute with this integral?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $\gamma: M \rightarrow M$ be a diffeomorphism. We denote by $\mathcal{A}(M)$ the algebra of differential forms. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}(M)$ be a smooth map. Suppose that $\int\limits_0 ^ {+\infty} f(t)dt$ iis a well defined differential form.

Does the following equality hold

$$ \gamma^*\left(\int\limits_0 ^ {+\infty} f(t)dt\right) = \int\limits_0 ^ {+\infty} \gamma^* (f(t)) dt ? $$

Comment: Could you please explain how to understand $\mathcal A(M)$ as a smooth manifold?

Comment: Actually I don't know any specific smooth structure on $\mathcal{A}(M)$. I think I shouldn't say that $f$ is smooth. I asked this question because I have an example of the function $f$,  and I would like to know whether it is possible to commute the pullback with the integral.